# How can I show a certain content in dependence of a simple model-related-query in Angular?

Tags: angularjs, show

How can I achieve following situation in Angular?

```
<div show if {{model.roles.length}} > 1 >

    show this content

</div>
```

Comment: which syntax in this context?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `ng-if` or `ng-show` in your context

```
<div ng-if="model.roles.length > 1">

   show this content

</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
<div  ng-show="model.roles.length > 1" >
 show the content
</div>
```